# Update query too slow on Postgres 9.1

Tags: regex, performance, postgresql

My problem is that I have a very slow update query on a table with 14 million rows. I tried different things to tune my server which brought good performance but not for update queries.

I have two tables:

- T1 with 4 columns and 3 indexes on it (530 rows)
- T2 with 15 columns and 3 indexes on it (14 millions rows)
- I want to update the field vid (type integer) in T2 by the same value of vid in T1 by joining the two tables on a text field stxt.

Here is my query and its output:

```
explain analyse 
update T2 
  set vid=T1.vid 
from T1 
where stxt2 ~ stxt1 and T2.vid = 0;
```

```
Update on T2  (cost=0.00..9037530.59 rows=2814247 width=131) (actual time=25141785.741..25141785.741 rows=0 loops=1)
 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..9037530.59 rows=2814247 width=131) (actual time=32.636..25035782.995 rows=679354 loops=1)
             Join Filter: ((T2.stxt2)::text ~ (T1.stxt1)::text)
             ->  Seq Scan on T2  (cost=0.00..594772.96 rows=1061980 width=121) (actual time=0.067..5402.614 rows=1037809 loops=1)
                         Filter: (vid= 1)
             ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..17.95 rows=530 width=34) (actual time=0.000..0.069 rows=530 loops=1037809)
                         ->  Seq Scan on T1  (cost=0.00..15.30 rows=530 width=34) (actual time=0.019..0.397 rows=530 loops=1)
Total runtime: 25141785.904 ms
```

As you can see the query took approximately 25141 seconds (~ 7 hours). f I understood well, the planner estimates the execution time to be 9037 seconds (~ 2.5 hours). Am I missing something here?

Here are information about my server config:

- CentOS 5.8, 20GB of RAM
- shared_buffers = 12GB
- work_mem = 64MB
- maintenance_work_mem = 64MB
- bgwriter_lru_maxpages = 500
- checkpoint_segments = 64
- checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
- effective_cache_size = 10GB

I have run vacuum full and analyse several times on table T2 but this still does not improve much the situation.

PS: if I set full_page_writes to off, this improves considerably update queries, but I don't want to risk data loss. Do you please have any recommandations?

Comment: Try using MERGE instead. It links the tables faster.

Comment: Do you really need the ~ operator ? what is in the stxt1, stxt2 fields, and what are their types ?

Comment: @wildplasser   the ~ operator is almost equivalent to `stxt2 like '%'||stxt1||'%'`. Both fields stxt are character varying.


@radashk     I tried this [link](http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com/2010/05/merge-syntax.html) but Postgres keeps telling me `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "MERGE"`. How exactly should I try "MERGE"?

Comment: 1) I know about what ~ means, but it appears you have the 500 regexes stored in table1. 2) There is no merge in postgresql (and it would not help in this case)

Comment: @wildplasser I don't know if there is another way to join the two tables, that's why I used the ~. If stxt2 contains stxt1, then I want T2.vid to be equal to T1.vid, otherwise nothing should happen. Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1) There are cases where indexes could help text searches (I am not an expert) 2) if the number of *distinct* values for the text field is smaller than the number of rows (in t2), you could pre-calculate a junction table and use that in the final query using exact matches.

Comment: both text fields are indexed. The problem is not in the jucntion itself, I've posted this query as an example but in general bulk update queries are too slow on big tables. As I said, setting full_page_writes to off helps so much but I don't think it is recommended.

Comment: Bulk-updates are not slow on exact matches; the above query could execute in sub-second time if the join were on integer, date or even "exact" character matches. BTW: out of curiosity: what is *in* the text fields: misspelled names ? URLs ?

Comment: stxt fields contain urls. For instance if stxt2=http:///www.somedomain.com/index.php and stxt1=somedomain.com the update should happen.

Comment: The cost values are not a direct time estimate thought there is a relation between the two. The cost parameter is only useful for comparing different plans. Your effective_cache_size value seems to be incorrect. It should include the sharedbuffer size so it should be somewhere between 12G and 20G for your system. http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

Comment: I've changed it to 14GB now. Thanks

Comment: The question is good, but may get better answers at dba.SE.

Comment: Can you build a functional index to match the stxt1 ~ stxt2 condition?

Comment: @Scott Marlowe

I didn't understand your question very well, but I think I should avoid the ~ operator as it is expensive as mentioned by memebers.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a solution, but a data-modelling work-around

- break up the urls into {protocol,hostname,pathname} components.
- Now you can use exact matches to join om the hostname part, avoiding the leading % in the regex-match.
- the view is intended to demonstrate that the full_url can be reconstructed if needed.

The update could probably take a few minutes.

```
SET search_path='tmp';

DROP TABLE urls CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE urls
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , full_url varchar
        , proto varchar
        , hostname varchar
        , pathname varchar
        );

INSERT INTO urls(full_url) VALUES
 ( 'ftp://www.myhost.com/secret.tgz' )
,( 'http://www.myhost.com/robots.txt' )
,( 'http://www.myhost.com/index.php' )
,( 'https://www.myhost.com/index.php' )
,( 'http://www.myhost.com/subdir/index.php' )
,( 'https://www.myhost.com/subdir/index.php' )
,( 'http://www.hishost.com/index.php' )
,( 'https://www.hishost.com/index.php' )
,( 'http://www.herhost.com/index.php' )
,( 'https://www.herhost.com/index.php' )
        ;

UPDATE urls
SET proto = split_part(full_url, '://' , 1)
        , hostname = split_part(full_url, '://' , 2)
        ;

UPDATE urls
SET pathname = substr(hostname, 1+strpos(hostname, '/' ))
        , hostname = split_part(hostname, '/' , 1)
        ;

        -- the full_url field is now redundant: we can drop it
ALTER TABLE urls
        DROP column full_url
        ;
        -- and we could always reconstruct the full_url from its components.
CREATE VIEW vurls AS (
        SELECT id
        , proto || '://' || hostname || '/' || pathname AS full_url
        , proto
        , hostname
        , pathname
        FROM urls
        );

SELECT * FROM urls;
        ;
SELECT * FROM vurls;
        ;
```

OUTPUT:

```
INSERT 0 10
UPDATE 10
UPDATE 10
ALTER TABLE
CREATE VIEW
 id | proto |    hostname     |     pathname     
----+-------+-----------------+------------------
  1 | ftp   | www.myhost.com  | secret.tgz
  2 | http  | www.myhost.com  | robots.txt
  3 | http  | www.myhost.com  | index.php
  4 | https | www.myhost.com  | index.php
  5 | http  | www.myhost.com  | subdir/index.php
  6 | https | www.myhost.com  | subdir/index.php
  7 | http  | www.hishost.com | index.php
  8 | https | www.hishost.com | index.php
  9 | http  | www.herhost.com | index.php
 10 | https | www.herhost.com | index.php
(10 rows)

 id |                full_url                 | proto |    hostname     |     pathname     
----+-----------------------------------------+-------+-----------------+------------------
  1 | ftp://www.myhost.com/secret.tgz         | ftp   | www.myhost.com  | secret.tgz
  2 | http://www.myhost.com/robots.txt        | http  | www.myhost.com  | robots.txt
  3 | http://www.myhost.com/index.php         | http  | www.myhost.com  | index.php
  4 | https://www.myhost.com/index.php        | https | www.myhost.com  | index.php
  5 | http://www.myhost.com/subdir/index.php  | http  | www.myhost.com  | subdir/index.php
  6 | https://www.myhost.com/subdir/index.php | https | www.myhost.com  | subdir/index.php
  7 | http://www.hishost.com/index.php        | http  | www.hishost.com | index.php
  8 | https://www.hishost.com/index.php       | https | www.hishost.com | index.php
  9 | http://www.herhost.com/index.php        | http  | www.herhost.com | index.php
 10 | https://www.herhost.com/index.php       | https | www.herhost.com | index.php
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Now try to run the two updates to obtain the {protocol, hostname, pathname} components in the temp table. Don't drop the full_url field yet.

Comment: I have an answer to post but I have to wait 27 minutes to do :). I am new and don't have enough reputation

Comment: BTW: you could use the above temp table as a junction table; translating full_url to (canonical?) hostnames.

Comment: I think this is in the correct direction. Not only is ~ expensive, but I wonder if it does what you want if T1.stx1 has rows with 'apple' and 'google' while T2.stx2 has 'www.appleiscoolerthangoogle.com'.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus

You're right about the ~. But for the comparison, I think it should  work most of the time because stxt1 contains a domain not a single word. For instance stxt1=somedomain.com and stxt2=sub1.somedomain.com.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an expanded example of my previous comment on a functional index.  If you use postgresql and don't know what a functional index is, you're probably suffering because of it.

Let's create a test table put some data in it:

```
smarlowe=# create table test (a text, b text, c int);
smarlowe=# insert into test select 'abc','z',0 from generate_series(1,1000000); -- 1 million rows that don't match
smarlowe=# insert into test select 'abc','a',0 from generate_series(1,10); -- 10 rows that do match
smarlowe=# insert into test select 'abc','z',1 from generate_series(1,1000000); -- another million rows that won't match.
```

Now we want to run some queries on it to test:

```
\timing
select * from test where a ~ b and c=0; -- ignore how long this takes
select * from test where a ~ b and c=0; -- run it twice to get a read with cached data.
```

On my laptop this takes ~750ms.  This classic index on c:

```
smarlowe=# create index test_c on test(c);
smarlowe=# select * from test where a ~ b and c=0;
```

takes ~400ms on my laptop.

This functional index tho:

```
smarlowe=# drop index test_c ;
smarlowe=# create index test_regex on test (c) where (a~b);
smarlowe=# select * from test where a ~ b and c=0;
```

**Now runs in 1.3ms.**

Of course there's no such thing as a free lunch, and you WILL pay for this index during updates / inserts.

Comment: There is a cost, of course, but a partial index with a selective `WHERE` clause like in your example is very cheap in comparison and leads to a tiny index. Very useful.

Comment: @Scott Marlowe Thank you for the hint. So functional indexes are partial indexes? I think I've read about them in the official documentation but never used them. I'm not sure but I thnik they only are usefull in some specefic cases.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, this brings some help. So here's what I did:

- I created the table urls as you mentioned
- I've added a vid column of type integer to it
- I inserted 1000000 rows in full_url column from T2
- I enabled timing, and updated the hostname column with full_url that do not contain neither 'http' nor 'www'
  `update urls set hostname=full_url where full_url not like '%/%' and full_url not like 'www\.%';`

`Time: 112435.192 ms`

Then I run this query:

```
    mydb=> explain analyse update urls set vid=vid from T1 where hostname=stxt1; 
             QUERY PLAN                                                          
            -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             Update on urls  (cost=21.93..37758.76 rows=864449 width=124) (actual time=767.793..767.793 rows=0 loops=1)
                 ->  Hash Join  (cost=21.93..37758.76 rows=864449 width=124) (actual time=102.324..430.448 rows=94934 loops=1)
                             Hash Cond: ((urls.hostname)::text = (T1.stxt1)::text)
                             ->  Seq Scan on urls  (cost=0.00..25612.52 rows=927952 width=114) (actual time=0.009..265.962 rows=927952 loops=1)
                             ->  Hash  (cost=15.30..15.30 rows=530 width=34) (actual time=0.444..0.444 rows=530 loops=1)
                                         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 35kB
                                         ->  Seq Scan on T1  (cost=0.00..15.30 rows=530 width=34) (actual time=0.002..0.181 rows=530 loops=1)
             Total runtime: 767.860 ms
```

I was really surprised by the total runtime! less than 1 sec which confirms what you said about updates with exact matches. Now I searched for exacts matches between xtxt1 and stxt2 this way:

```
mydb=> select count(*) from T2 where vid is null and exists(select null from T1 where stxt1=stxt2);
 count  
--------
 308486
(1 row)
```

Thus I tried the update on T2 table, and got this:

```
mydb=> explain analyse update T2 set vid = T1.vid from T1 where T2.vid is null and stxt2=stxt1;
                                                                                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on T2  (cost=21.93..492023.13 rows=2106020 width=131) (actual time=252395.118..252395.118 rows=0 loops=1)
     ->  Hash Join  (cost=21.93..492023.13 rows=2106020 width=131) (actual time=1207.897..4739.515 rows=308486 loops=1)
                 Hash Cond: ((T2.stxt2)::text = (T1.stxt1)::text)
                 ->  Seq Scan on T2  (cost=0.00..455452.09 rows=4130377 width=121) (actual time=158.773..3915.379 rows=4103865 loops=1)
                             Filter: (vid IS NULL)
                 ->  Hash  (cost=15.30..15.30 rows=530 width=34) (actual time=0.293..0.293 rows=530 loops=1)
                             Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 35kB
                             ->  Seq Scan on T1  (cost=0.00..15.30 rows=530 width=34) (actual time=0.005..0.121 rows=530 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 252395.204 ms
(9 rows)

Time: 255389.704 ms
```

Actually 255 sec seems to be a very good time for such a query. I'll try to extract the hostname part from all urls and make the update. I still should make sure that updating with exact matches is fast cause I had bad experience with it.

Thank you for your support.