# SQL query to compare 2 host URLs

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to compare 2 URL hostname and categorise them as equal or not equal.

For example,

- `www.abcd.com/xyz` and `https://www.abcd.com/def` should be treated as equal
- `www.abcd.com` and `https://www.abcd.com/xyz` should be treated as equal.
- `www.abcd.com/xyz` and `www.abcdef.com/xyz` should be treated as not equal.
- `www.abcd.com/xyz` and `www.xyz.com/pqr` should be treated as not equal

I am currently using-

```
Case WHEN regexp_match(a, 'www.*/'::text) = regexp_match(b, 'www.*/'::text)  THEN 'Direct'::text
CASE WHEN (regexp_match(tdahw.event_value, 'www.*/'::text) <> regexp_match(a, 'www.*/'::text)   THEN 'Referrer'::text
```

I am not able to handle the last case using this.
I only want to categorise them into equal and unequal. One column contains url without `https` and 1 is with `https`.

Comment: You could split the urls into their components: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11384025/905902 This will make comparing very easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to deal with `https://` you can e.g. use `trim` for that:

```
trim(leading 'https://' from url_1) = trim(leading 'https://' from url_2)
```

If you want to deal with `https` and `http` alike, regexp_replace can be used:

```
regexp_replace(url_1, '^https{0,1}://', '') = regexp_replace(url_2, '^https{0,1}://', '')
```

If you need that often, you can put that into a SQL function.

Comment: @AbHiNaVAgRaWaL: if you want something else, you should have added that information in your question. [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65696463/edit)  and add your attempt as formatted text. Don't put code or additional information into comments. More detailed sample data and expected output would also help to avoid answers that don't help you.